Problems to pray in time
Assalamu alaykum, I have two questions, in the summer I will be at a wedding in a restaurant, and the time it will take place is from 7:30 pm to 1:00/2:00 am, and during this time it would be difficult for me to pray maghrib and isha, because outside the restaurant there is no room because the car parks are narrow and there is no space, and they won't let you leave the restaurant because the gates are closed, and my parents can pray maghrib and isha at 7:00 pm (maghrib time would be 8:00pm and isha time would be 10:30pm) what can I do?
